# Wordpress search today, past week, past month

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm still learning php, but this is way too difficult for me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Basically I'm trying to code a search for my wordpress, so that visitors could select a time frame of posts being made, just like in Google Search.

Drop down near the search box:

- Today.
- Past Week
- Past Month.
- Year to date.
- Past Year.
- Any time.

Right now I only have a working search code:

```
    <form action="/" method="get">
      <input type="text" name="s"  placeholder="Symbol" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the answer.

You can have buttons on your page:

Today, Yesterday, Past 7 days, Past Month, Past Year, All time.

When you click, the loop will display only posts made during that period of time.

Here are the codes (add them to index.php):

1. Add this code where you want your buttons to be displayed:

```
    <a href="?d=<?php date("d", strtotime( '-0 days' ) );
    echo date("d", strtotime( '-0 days' ) ); ?>"> Today </a> 
    <a href="?d=<?php date("d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
    echo date("d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) ); ?>"> Yesterday </a>
    <a href="?period=7daysago"> Past Week </a>
    <a href="?period=31daysago"> Past Month </a>
    <a href="?period=365daysago"> Past Year </a>
    <a href="?alltime"> All Time </a>
```

2. Then after the first one, add this code:

```
                <?php 
    // Limit query posts to the current day
    // 
    $period = $_GET["period"];
    $day = $_GET["d"];
    $year = $_GET["y"]; 
    $args = array(
        'year' => (int) date($year),    
        'monthnum' => (int) date( 'M' ),    
        'day' => (int) date($day), 
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => ($period), 
            )
        )
        
    );
    
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    // The Loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        $query->the_post();
            
  // LOOP content goes here
                
    endwhile;

    
    ?>
```

I'm sure you can easily do a dropbox menu using css if you want.

As a newbie, it took a while to figured it all out.

Enjoy.